# Elegant error checking

Tags: c, error-handling

Our code (in a simple library implementation) is beginning to look like this:

```
err = callToUnderlyingLibrary1();
if (err!=0) {
printf ("blah %d\n", err);
...
}

err = callToUnderlyingLibrary2();
if (err!=0) {
printf ("blah %d\n", err);
...
}

err = callToUnderlyingLibrary3();
if (err!=0) {
printf ("blah %d\n", err);
...
}
```

This is cumbersome and ugly. Is there a better way to do this ? Perhaps using the C preprocessor ? I was thinking something like:

```
CHECK callToUnderlyingLibrary1();
CHECK callToUnderlyingLibrary2();
CHECK callToUnderlyingLibrary3();
```

where the CHECK macro invokes the function and does the rudimentary error checking.

Are there preferred idiomatic ways of handling this ?

Comment: You should probably pick either C or C++, not both.  In C++, the canonical answer will involve exceptions.  In C, it will not.

Comment: Good idea. Let me remove the C++ tag.

Comment: I wish I could give more `UP votes`!!!

Comment: As you originally tagged it C and C++, is it a fair assumption that this involves a C library being invoked from C++ code??

Comment: @Roddy: Yes. But our code is really a very thin layer on top of the C library, so it is really C for all practical purposes.

Comment: + 1 for wanting a better way to do this :)

Answer (score 23):

Another macro-based approach which you can use to mitigate the shortcomings in C fairly easily:

```
#define CHECK(x) do { \
  int retval = (x); \
  if (retval != 0) { \
    fprintf(stderr, "Runtime error: %s returned %d at %s:%d", #x, retval, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    return /* or throw or whatever */; \
  } \
} while (0)
```

Then to invoke it you have:

```
CHECK(doSomething1());
CHECK(doSomething2());
// etc.
```

For bonus points you could easily extend the CHECK macro to take a second argument y that is what to do on failure:

```
#define CHECK(x, y) do { \
  int retval = (x); \
  if (retval != 0) { \
    fprintf(stderr, "Runtime error: %s returned %d at %s:%d", #x, retval, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    y; \
  } \
} while (0)

// We're returning a different error code
CHECK(someFunction1(foo), return someErrorCode);
// We're actually calling it from C++ and can throw an exception
CHECK(someFunction2(foo), throw SomeException("someFunction2 failed")):
```

Comment: Why do you choose to use a macro, and not a function / inline function?

Comment: @alexs973 Because in this case the thing needs to be able to return from the function that's calling it, and also the question was for C-language so exceptions are not supported.

Comment: Is there anyway to obtain information about the function being called or its parameters?

Comment: @Julian The `#x` parameter to `fprintf` includes the string version of the first parameter in the error log. What additional information are you trying to obtain? Unfortunately preprocessor macros are pretty limited in what sort of scope-level information they can get.

Answer (score 16):

Usually, in C, one uses `goto` for error handling:

```
int foo()
{
    if (Function1() == ERROR_CODE) goto error;
    ...
    struct bar *x = acquire_structure;
    ...
    if (Function2() == ERROR_CODE) goto error0;
    ...

    release_structure(x);
    return 0;

error0:
    release_structure(x);

error:
    return -1;
}
```

This can be improved with macros and more clever instruction flow (to avoid repeating cleanup code), but I hope you see the point.

Comment: Gotos in Macros :-) Thanks for reminding me why I program in C++ when possible!

Comment: @Roddy: if you keep the functions short and if you have some discipline, there is nothing wrong with this approach. Gotos and macros have their use here.

Comment: These `goto`s are not in macros! :)

Comment: @Alexandre: yes - in C you have to live with the cards that the language has dealt you - and Macros and gotos are essential ones. But personally, I don't have the necessary disipline to stay in control of that, which is why C++ and RAII works for me :-)

Comment: @Roddy: sure, you're right. I stay away from C when I can. Sometimes you don't have the choice of the language though.

Comment: Gotos in macros can be quite nice, however _always_ pass the label to jump to as a parameter to the macro. This makes the macro more flexible as well as not hiding that execution might continue somewhere other than the next line.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should look at exceptions and exception handling. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

```
try{    
    callToUnderlyingLibrary1();
    callToUnderlyingLibrary2();
    callToUnderlyingLibrary3();
}catch(exception& e)
    //Handle exception
}
```

your library functions can throw exceptions if there is an error

Comment: Yes, that would have been nice, but unfortunately, it's not an option for us. We are tied to using a certain underlying library, which does not throw exceptions.

Comment: I won't downvote since the C++ tag has been removed after your answer. But the question deals with C, which has no `try/catch` construct.

Comment: Right. My fault for including the C++ tag to begin with. Please don't downvote this answer, which would apply correctly to C++.

Comment: @Ren: Can you make a C++ wrapper for the library, then? Usability of most C libraries can be enormously improved for C++ with wrapper classes and a sprinkling of RAII and exceptions.

Comment: @Roddy: Noted. I think that would be a good long-term enhancement of the codebase.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proposition, you may or may not like it:

- make your functions return 0 on failure, something else on success
- if something fails in your functions, have them set a global (or static) variable to the error code (like `errno`)
- create a `die()` function that prints the error depending of the error code (or whatever you want it to do)
- call your functions with `do_something(foo, bar) || die("Argh...");`

Comment: If your functions returned 0 on success, `do_something(foo, bar) || die("Argh...");` would call `die` on success.

Comment: This technique tends to generate spurious compiler warnings about 'value calculated is not used' unless you wrap it `(void)(...)`

Answer (score 3):

I prefer a variant of Alexandra C.'s goto-approach:

```
int foo()
{
    int rv = 0;
    struct bar *x = NULL;
    struct bar *y = NULL;
    rv = Function1();
    if (rv != OK){
      goto error;
    }
    //...
    x = acquire_structure();
    if (x==NULL){
      rv = ERROR_MEMORY;
      goto error;
    }
    //...
    rv = Function2();
    if (rv != OK){
      goto error;
    }
    //...
    y = acquire_structure();
    if (y==NULL){
      rv = ERROR_MEMORY;
      goto error;
    }
    //...

    rv = release_structure(x);
    x = NULL;
    if (rv != OK){
      goto error;
    }
    rv = release_structure(y);
    y = NULL;
    if (rv != OK){
      goto error;
    }
    return OK;

error:
    if (x!=NULL){
      release_structure(x);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

When you use multiple goto-destinations, it is easy to mix them up. Or perhaps you move the initialization of a variable, but forget to update the gotos. And it can be very difficult to test *all* ways a C-method can fail.

I prefer having a single goto-destination that performs all the cleanup. I find that makes it easier to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You could do what you said, which is some rudimentary macro:

```
#define CHECK(x) (err = x()); \
                 if (err) { \
                      printf("blah %d on line %d of file %s\n", err, __LINE__, __FILE__); \
                 } \
                 else (void)0
```

And you could use it like

```
int err = 0;
CHECK(callToUnderlyingLibrary1); // don't forget the semicolon at the end
CHECK(callToUnderlyingLibrary2);
CHECK(callToUnderlyingLibrary3);
```

Comment: That's pretty bad macro style that leads to all sorts of weird parse issues, not to mention you have a macro that's suddenly expecting something about variables in the enclosing scope.

Comment: @fluffy What are some examples of weird parse issues?

Comment: if (someCondition) CHECK(blah); else CHECK(otherblah); - it's better to wrap a multi-statement macro in a do { ... } while (0)  for this reason as it fixes pretty much all those situations.

Comment: @fluffy why would `if (someCondition) CHECK(blah); else CHECK(otherblah);` cause problems?

Comment: Because it's a multi-line expression, but CHECK is not enclosed in curly braces. Expand the macro out yourself; you end up with:  `if (someCondition) (err=x()); if(err){...}else (void)0; else (etc.)` which doesn't even parse.

Comment: @fluffy ah ok, I see what you mean.

Answer (score -5):

No 'goto', use only 1 'return' in functions. That's the elegant code.

IMHO, OP's question point and all answers are talking about FANCY techniques. Fancy code is just sort of eye candy.

Comment: what does it mean to have elegant code: https://www.quora.com/What-does-one-mean-by-elegant-code . one return statement has little value and usually stems from a misconception: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from